VTrak No loadable IBL_RAM image. Reset to Engineering mode
I have VTrak  M610i. I could not connect with mgmt port. But iSCSI still works.
Next I connected with console cable and see lile next. Then I did reboot and it says:
islavista> reboot
islavista> Restarting subsystem. Please wait.

Engineering mode Active

Reseting watchdog .... done
16 port new, 400W_2U_new, 400W_2U_new
+NAND flash ID = 00 00 00 00
This NAND flash chip is not supported!
Ethernet eth0: MAC address 00:01:55:40:b2:fd
IP: 192.168.128.80/255.255.255.192, Gateway: 192.168.128.65
Default server: 0.0.0.0, DNS server IP: 0.0.0.0

IBL_ROM Ver 1.08.0000.00
Built 17:11:54, Oct  2 2007
Core speed : 500 MHz
RAM: 0x00000000-0x10000000, 0x0001b918-0x07fb1000 available
FLASH: 0xc0000000 - 0xc0f00000, 120 blocks of 0x00020000 bytes each.
Clear firmware space for battery backup function diabled.
No loadable IBL_RAM image. Reset to Engineering mode.
== Executing boot script in 3.000 seconds - enter ^C to abort
IBL_ROM> fis load kernel
... Unlock from 0xc0ec0000-0xc0f00000: ..
Turn 7 HD's power on
Turn 5 HD's power on
Turn 4 HD's power on
IBL_ROM> go -n 0x01008000
Loading software modules .................................................md5sum: /islavista/conf/scripts/start_sh: Input/output error
cp: unable to stat `/islavista/conf/scripts/start_sh': Input/output error
islavista>


How can I recover it?
Thanks
I can only reboot. ISCSI still work. But I want to check/upgrade drives.
